# Silence detection of microphone input in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, audio

I am writing a voice assistant flutter application for **linux** similar to an Amazon Alexa. For recording microphone input i am using the package "record". The package writes the input audio inside a .m4a audio file.
I want to stop recording Audio if there is silence for 2 seconds.

I know, that when starting the recording the file gets written in my temp-folder and while its recording the file size increases. I've tried looking at the different file sizes while talking and while being silent, but it seems that loudness doesn't really have an effect on the file size.

Parallel to the record package i am using vosk_flutter, which gives me a stream of words that are currently spoken. I had the idea of using the output of that stream to detect silence by looking whether the returned strings are empty or not. However the results of vosk are not too reliable and i find it way more practical to look at something like e.g. an amplitude value, since it would be more customizable.

I've also tried looking for other packages to record my microphone with, but most aren't compatible with linux, so i think i need to stick to 'record'.

There has been a question on here similar to mine, but it hasn't been answered yet:
[How to detect silence while recording audio in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493335/how-to-detect-silence-while-recording-audio-in-flutter)